# Using Nextjs Image component with different image sizes

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, nextjs-image

I am trying to use the Next.js Image component with images that all have unique sizes. [Their example](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#layout) states the image will stretch to the parent div width and height. I've tried wrapping them but don't know how to accommodate dynamic image sizes. I want to have a set width and the height to adjust to each respective proportion. TIA.

Here is my code (the images are coming from an array) -- since I don't have a height set nothing renders on the page. If i use Tailwind's `h-auto` it still does not display:

```js
<div className="w-screen h-screen">
  {allImages.allImages.map((image, i) => {
    return (
      <div className="relative w-100 md:w-5/6 lg:w-7/12" key={image}>
        <Image priority src={`/${image}`} layout="fill" objectFit="cover" />
      </div>
  )})}
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution in this [article](https://dev.to/felixhaeberle/responsive-fix-for-the-next-js-image-component-1351) which seems to work.

```jsx
<div className="image-container">
  <Image src={path} layout="fill" className="image" />
</div>
```

SCSS

```scss
.image-container {
  width: 100%;

  > div {
    position: unset !important;
  }

  .image {
    object-fit: contain;
    width: 100% !important;
    position: relative !important;
    height: unset !important;
  }
}
```

I wrapped this in a component named `<ResponsiveImage />`. You can try other rules on the wrapper, such as `position: relative`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these props on the Image tag,

```
<div className="div-class">
   <Image src={imageLink} layout="fill" objectFit="cover" />
</div>
```

and wrap the Image tag in a div, just as above. Now you can give width and height to the div with media queries and the image will use that space.